# What is my problem in linking a function defined in config.cpp to my headerfile allvariables.hpp?

Tags: c++, makefile

```
obj/main_exec.o: In function `std::ctype<char>::do_widen(char) const':
/home/aj/Documents/02_AJ_Research/13_Striker/ext/SimuFlow_1.0/src/configmod.cpp:7: multiple definition of `ty_conf::setconf_fromfile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, int*, int*)'
obj/configmod.o:/home/aj/Documents/02_AJ_Research/13_Striker/ext/SimuFlow_1.0/src/configmod.cpp:7: first defined here
```

There is a header file with a class and it a public declaration of a function exist: when compiled the `config.o` file says the function is already defined in `config.cpp`. 
Why is this causing a linker error?

Information
`ty_Conf` is a class defined in the header: everything inside is public including the function declaration: `setconf_fromfile(...);`
The definition of the function is found in `configmod.cpp`

seeking any help regarding this

The Following are my Makefile Commands:

```
**# object list
HOBJ  = $(OBJ_DIR)/allvariables.o\
OBJS  = $(OBJ_DIR)/linker.o\
        $(OBJ_DIR)/configmod.o\
EXEC  = $(OBJ_DIR)/flus_exec.o
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.hpp
        $(CPP) -c $< -o $@ $(FFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) #$(CFLAGS)
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
        $(CPP) -c $< -o $@ $(FFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) #$(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: all build externals clean distclean
all: externals build
build:  $(HOBJ) $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
        $(CPP) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(EXE) $(OBJS) $(EXEC) $(FFLAGS)    $(LFLAGS)**
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at our [help section](https://stackoverflow.com), with particular attention to [the page on minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You haven't given us enough information to reproduce the bug. It appears that somehow the function is defined in two source files (`configmod.cpp` and `main_exec.cpp` perhaps?). I don't suppose you remember the last change you made before the bug appeared, do you?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your output directories and then re-trying the build? (Not sure if your make file cleans it completely)

Comment: I have only shown the relevant part of the Makefile- Should you prefer I can show the entirety. There is an obvious solution to the problem: It is to make the function ty_conf::setconf_fromfile(..) as inline in the function definition. But I would like to know why this is an issue ?